# How to clear Windows 10 bios wake timers using Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-10, bios, wake-on-demand

A Windows 10 installation on my notebook has set wake timers, preventing me from storing it without destroying the battery. I have since replaced that "operating system" with Linux, but the wake timers remain. How do I clear those timers using Linux?

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by the Windows 10 "modern suspend". This can be changed in BIOS config->power om my Lenovo ThinkPad at least. When avtive, the PC may wake up for updates and similar, if the power cable is in, but it is well behaved when running from battery only.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).